# Deriving a Laurent series (not taking derivative)

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

[image]

I have to derive this series, as in reproduce it not differentiate.

Here's what I have:

I write $\frac{1}{4z-z^2}$ as $\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{4-z}$ and then divide $1/4$ out of the second term, so
$$
\frac{1}{4z}\frac{1}{1-z/4}
$$
and expand the second term.
$$
\frac{1}{4z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{4^n}
$$
then multiplying the $\frac{1}{4z}$ term through and pulling off the first term i get
$$
\frac{1}{4z} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n-2}}{4^n}
$$
what did i do wrong?

Comment: How can we know what you did wrong if you don't tell us what you attempted to do?!

Comment: i'm sorry but I think I have showed you what  I attempted to do, it's in the OP.

I rewrote the fraction in a special way and expanded one term, pulled off a term, adjusted the index..

I didn't put the "cleaner" stuff in latex because it takes time and I have the final exam soon..

Comment: Well, you didn't: you even didn't say around **what** point to writhe the Laurent series...! And the "explanation" of time to write in a sloppy way instead of a nice looking, *clear* one is unacceptable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{4z}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{4^n}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n-1}}{4^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{4z}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n-1}}{4^{n+1}}.$$
Reindexing the last sum by $k=n-1$ gives the correct result:
$$\frac{1}{4z}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n-1}}{4^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{4z}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{k}}{4^{k+2}}.$$